# Create a function that has 3 parameters: list of integers (num), integer number (n1), and another integer number (n2)

Tags: python

**The function will return a list of integers that are multiples of either n1 or n2.**

*This is my code*

```
def exercise_3(nums, n1, n2): 
    multiples = []
    for i in nums:
        if i % n1 == 0 and i % n2 == 0:
            multiples.append(i)
    return multiples
```

*It gives an Assertion Error*

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 ans = exercise_3(np.arange(20), 3, 4)
----> 2 assert ans==[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 18]
      4 ans = exercise_3(np.arange(300), 17, 27)
      5 assert ans==[17, 27, 34, 51, 54, 68, 81, 85, 102, 108, 119, 135, 136, 153, 162, 170, 187, 189, 204, 216, 221, 238, 243, 255, 270, 272, 289, 297]

AssertionError:
```

Comment: please post the full code. I can see the error is something else that is NOT related to the code you posted

Comment: Isn't `0` an integer why is is not part of the asserted answer? `0` is a multiple of everything and is the first element of `np.arange(20)` and `np.arange(300)`?  Could the question be asking for positive integers? `return [n for n in nums if n > 0 and (n % n1 == 0 or n % n2 == 0)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per question, you are required to find `The function will return a list of integers that are multiples of either n1 or n2.`

integer which are multiple of n1 or n2. ie if any integer of any one of n1 or n2, it is fine.

so in you code you have wrote `if i % n1 == 0 and i % n2 == 0:` which say that integer should be multiple of n1 as well as n2.

so this is contradactory of question. so you need to change `and` to `or`. making code as
`if i % n1 == 0 or i % n2 == 0`

also your test case value start from 1 and 0 not included so , you start value in your `np.arange` should be 1. so you should  provide `nums` as `np.arange(1, 20)` in functional call.

so here is the corrected code

```
def exercise_3(nums, n1, n2): 
    multiples = []
    for i in nums:
        if i==0:
            continue 
        if i % n1 == 0 or i % n2 == 0:
            multiples.append(i)
    return multiples
```